# single or set of patches from windows update?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, command-line-interface, windows-update

Is there a way to install several patches by kb or other means and only install those specific without manually downloading the patches? I want to use automatic update services but don't want every critical update.  I want to draw up a list.

I know with WSUS I can use patch groups, but I would like to handle the cherry picking at the client.

Perhaps with powershell or cli?

Answer (score 1):

If you use custom mode in Windows Update you can select the specific patches you wish to apply.

Comment: yes, how do you do that from the command line?